# Is there any way to tell if any givin Number will either blow up or tend towards a Value when squared?

Tags: complex-numbers, fractals

Ok so as a Set Up, i want to do the all time classy, the Mandelbrot set. As far as i know, the equation

$$Z \rightarrow Z²+C$$

Just asks the question "Ok givin any Complex Number, if you Square the Non Complex terme and then Add the Complex compnent, is this new number something REALLY huge or does it tend towards a Value ?

Of course, normaly this Equation is based on Iterations so you do that a bunch of times and bam, either your Value is huge for small.

But, there is sort of a Problem for me. At the moment, my code spits out this:[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OFLAl.png)

I dont want to be a downer but that doest really look right. My guess is that the Problem is how huge the values get once you square them a few times. And since Computers are pretty dumb, at some point Values might switch from Positive to negative and so on.

So, to the question, please tell me there is a fancy Algorithm that can just tell me if Z will be huge or small D:

Thanks !

Comment: "square the noncomplex term and add the complex component"??? Well, no. You square the complex number, $Z$, and then add the constant $C$, which could be real or not. And you do it over and over. And the Mandelbrot set is the values of $Z$ for which that iteration doesn't go off to infinity. And the way to tell is by doing the computations and seeing what happens.

Comment: Wait what. God damit, this would explain some stuff... Leme try it

Comment: To get much detail, you will need to work in a much higher precision that a typical double type.

Comment: @badjohn:  you can get some nice images using standard doubles.  As you zoom in more you need more precision.  I believe the original calculations were done with 32 bit floats, but am not sure.

Comment: @RossMillikan I see from WA Dom's answer that standard doubles work better than I remember.

Answer (score 1):

The 'normal' Mandelbrot set is derived by plotting the values of $c \in \mathbb C$ such that the sequence $z_{n+1} = z_n^2 + c, z_0 = 0$ remains bounded.

You can verify the sequence diverges when either (a) $|c| > 2$, or, (b), when $|c| \leqslant 2$, and at some stage $|z_n| > 2$.  This allows you to determine when to stop testing the $z_n$.

I don't believe there is any shortcut other than simply trying repeatedly to check on which $c$ led to divergence or not.

Using standard double arithmetic you can create reasonable images as illustrated (1)

[image: A portion of the Mandelbrot set]

or (2)

[image]